# Is 'phonegap serve' acceptable to use for production

Tags: cordova, mobile, web-applications, phonegap

I have a mobile app that was developed using phonegap. We have been deploying it to iOS and Android, but I would like to try deploying it as web app that runs in the phone's browser. I have built the app with

```
phonegap build browser
```

and I found that I can deploy it by creating a systemd service that contains something like:

```
phonegap serve --port 3002 --proxy
```

This is working for my personal testing. However, the documentation is leading me to believe that phonegap serve is mainly just meant for testing purposes. Is it acceptable to use phonegap serve in production or does it not scale well?

If not, is there some way to deploy the app using another web server like nginx? And is there any functionality I might lose by doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think using `phongap serve` is reasonable in production. `phongap serve` will spin up a small webserver for testing, but it is built for testing and is neither hardened nor built for best performance. So you should use a "production" webserver like nginx or apache.

To do so you should run `phonegap build browser` (you might want to add the `--release` flag). This should create a new directory (`/platforms/browser`) where you will find a `www` directory in. You can then serve this `www` directory with your webserver.

In terms of functionality you might loose some compared to a native app: Phonegap plugins might not work in browser. Some are supported on the browser platform, others are not. You might want to check out [this article](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/03/22/the-cordova-browser-platform), it describes plugin usage on the browser platform in more details.